# How to create popup menu with horizontal sub-menu in SEMANTIC

Tags: popup, semantic-ui, submenu, popupmenu

I wanna create horizontal sub menu when I click dropdown menu with SEMANTIC CSS. I just want like picture below. Thank you in advance!

[image: desired result]

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is not a dropdown menu , you're looking for Popup , you can  create your horizontal sub menu by creating first your menu button , then linking it to your Popup Content , like the following :

[[Demo]](https://codepen.io/SaadRegal/pen/prJvMQ?editors=1010)

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui text menu">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://semantic-ui.com/images/new-school.jpg">
  </div>
<!--   Your menu button  -->
  <a class="browse item">
    Browse Courses
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  </a>
 <!--   /Your menu button  -->
</div>

<!-- Your Popup Content -->
<div class="ui flowing basic admission popup">
  <div class="ui three column relaxed divided grid">
    <div class="column">
      <h4 class="ui header">Business</h4>
      <div class="ui link list">
        <a class="item">Design &amp; Urban Ecologies</a>
        <a class="item">Fashion Design</a>
        <a class="item">Fine Art</a>
        <a class="item">Strategic Design</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h4 class="ui header">Liberal Arts</h4>
      <div class="ui link list">
        <a class="item">Anthropology</a>
        <a class="item">Economics</a>
        <a class="item">Media Studies</a>
        <a class="item">Philosophy</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h4 class="ui header">Social Sciences</h4>
      <div class="ui link list">
        <a class="item">Food Studies</a>
        <a class="item">Journalism</a>
        <a class="item">Non Profit Management</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /Your Popup Content -->
```

**JS(jQuery)**

```
$('a.browse.item')
  .popup({
  popup : $('.ui.flowing.basic.admission.popup'),//Popup Content selector 
  on    : 'click', //Event trigger
  position   : 'bottom left',
  lastResort:true,
  })
;
```

In popup settings you can choose your event trigger like `on:'click'` , it can be either like: focus,hover... , for more settings see [Popup Settings](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#/settings).

[[DOCS]](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html)